# how to get values from database in codeigniter based on select box value without refreshing page?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Unable to get value from database in codeigniter. I tried to fetch data based on select box value(menu_code) without refreshing page using ajax but I got result undefined.

This my controller's code : `login.php`

```
public function get_menu_rights()
{
    if (isset($_POST['name']))
    {       
        $root_id = $this->input->post('menu_root_id');

        $data['res'] = $this->login_model->get_menu_check($root_id);
        // print_r($data['res']);
        echo json_encode($data);
        //$this->load->view('pages/role_rights',$data);     
    }
}
```

Below is my model code `login_model.php`

```
public function get_menu_check($root_id)
{       
    $this->db->select('menu_code,menu_name');       
    $this->db->from('create_menu as C1');   
    $this->db->where('C1.menu_root_id',$root_id);       
    $this->db->order_by('menu_code');

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

This is my view code `role_rights.php`

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('login/get_menu_rights');?>" method="post">
    <?php
     print"<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"menu_root_id\" onchange=\"javascript:__doPostBack();\" id=\"menu_root_id\">"; ?>                                       <option value="select">select</option>
                        <?php foreach($result as $res) { ?>                             
                    <option value="<?php echo $res->menu_code; ?>">
                    <?php echo $res->menu_name.'-'.$res->menu_code; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function __doPostBack()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('menu_root_id').value; 
            var dataString='name='+ name;
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"<?php echo base_url('login/get_menu_rights'); ?>",
                data:dataString,
                cache:false,
                dataType: 'json',                  
              success: function(data)        
              {
                var id = data[0];             
                var vname = data[1]; 
                $('#output').html("<b>menu_code: </b>"+id+"<b> menu_name: </b>"+vname); 
              }
            });
            return false;
        }
        </script>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: `$data['res'] = ...` You're putting the result row within 'res'. So you need to access it the same way.  `data.res.menu_code`

Comment: yes i tried but it doesn't work dude.

Comment: Put the JSON returned by the request in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

**Replace**

```
$root_id = $this->input->post('menu_root_id');
```

**with**

```
$root_id = $this->input->post('name');
```

Your controller's `get_menu_rights` method  should be like this :

```
public function get_menu_rights()
{
  $root_id = $this->input->post('name');
  if(! empty($root_id))
  {
    $data = $this->login_model->get_menu_check($root_id);
    // print_r($data);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;   
   }
}
```

Your ajax `success` function should be like this :

```
success: function(data)        
{
  var html = '';
  $.each(data,function(k,v){
    alert(v);
    html += "<b>menu_code: </b>"+v.menu_code+"<b> menu_name: </b>"+v.menu_name
  });
  $('#output').html(html); 
}
```

Comment: but still it displays like this (menu_code: undefined menu_name: undefined). i passing my selected box value into ajax and getting response from ajax.So,i think i maked mistake in ajax..but i donno where...

Comment: where and on which file/line u r getting that error?

Comment: i got error on <div id="output"></div>  i think i'm not properly getting response using ajax from controller

Comment: see your browser's console and network tab for the output and use code of my answer

Comment: it displays undefined ..but when i change   echo json_encode($data[''res]); it displays
 menu_code:  [object Object] menu_name: [object Object]

Comment: Are u getting single record or multiple record based on `$root_id;`

Comment: i got all values from db ...response in console successfully bro but how to display in my view file?{res: Array(2)}
res
:
Array(2)
0
:
{menu_code: "2", menu_name: "Plant"}
1
:
{menu_code: "3", menu_name: "Line"}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: ok , parse this data in your ajax, since it contains array data so you have to loop it see my updated answer for success function

Comment: bro but still it displays [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: this is because it is an array of object you have to loop through it

Comment: your updated success function prints output into my html div but i need to store it into php variable or array? Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I noticed

1. `$data` is an undefined array & you are settings the result array returned by the model function to it's `'res'` key
2. `dataString` is not a json neither it's a js array that you are sending
3. since you used `json_encode`, you need to use `JSON.parse(data)` in the ajax success
4. if you do have the result in `$data['res']`, then you need to do something like this - `data=JSON.parse(data)['res'];` now you can get `id` from `data[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the query return empty please try this Code.....

```
 public function get_menu_check($root_id)
        {
                $data = $this->db->select('C1.menu_code,C1.menu_name')
                                 ->from('create_menu as C1')
                                 ->where('C1.menu_root_id',$root_id)
                                 ->order_by('C1.menu_code')
                                 ->get();
               if($data->num_rows() >= 0)
                  return $data->result_array();
               else
                  return false;
        }
```

Comment: still it displays undefined

Comment: please use last_query function.to check the query result like

Comment: $this->db->last_query(); add this statement after get(); function and copy the result and direct check in phpmyadmin.if the query give you some result then the query is correct and the error was in your controller.

Comment: on ajax call in success just put console.log(data) at the top of function and watch the console. what is return ?

Comment: got response in console but how to display in view file?
{menu_code: "2", menu_name: "Plant"}
{menu_code: "3", menu_name: "Line"}